# URL rewriting issue when using / in url pattern

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I am having problem in URL rewriting using .htaccess file, problem is as below.

When I put below code in my .htaccess file on server

```
RewriteRule ^/?xyz http://google.com [R=301]
```

and I call url MY_WEB_DOMAIN.COM/xyza in browser it redirects me to google.com ( as expected )

And if I call url MY_WEB_DOMAIN.COM/xyz/abc I get 404 error..

isn't it should redirect to google on both case?
or something else is affecting my code with I use / (slash) in my pattern?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a) what is the '?' doing in there and b) you could try appending a 'wildcard': RewriteRule ^/xyz.* http://google.com [R=301]

Comment: Patriks: I do know what the '?' is meant to express in a regex, but it does not make any sense in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting was working ok.

I checked headers on server side for rewritten URL and directly called url.
I found only one change.

in direct url It was containing redirect_url and request_uri were same.. for rewriten url both were different.
(I thought oxwall might be using request_uri to process.. where as it was not as I wanted to be..

So I just made them same for rewritten url in php. by placing line
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];

And It is done. :)

Answer (score 1):

arkascha is right. Use this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?xyz.* http://www.google.com [R=301]
```

the /? makes that first / optional, which is sort of asinine in this case. But the .* is what you want to catch anything matching /xyz-----

if arkascha posts that as an answer you should accept it.
I tested this and it works fine. If it doesnt work for you check what lines you have above this rule in htaccess. you may have a conflict.

Comment: Hi Kai Qing, Thanks for response. I tried "RewriteRule ^/?xyz.* http://www.google.com [R=301]"
And What happen is as below. 
1. when I call url "xxxxx.com/xyza" or "xxxxx.com/xyza/anything" (in browser)
It redirects me to google (as expected)
2. when I call url "xxxxx.com/xyz" or "xxxxx.com/xyz/anything"
It redirects me to "xxxxx.com/oxwall/404" (as it should not)

Comment: {oxwall is a folder in my public_html folder, which contains a (php)framework installed named as oxwall}

*there are no rules above to this rule,except some of like "RewriteEngin on"

Comment: This .htaccess file is in main public_html folder, which is main folder.
There is another .htaccess file inside oxwall folder, I think it should not affect our work.
Am I right?

Comment: I used "http: //google.com" (ignore space) instead of "google.com", It is just typing mistake in above comment.